# How to enumerate all in-place holds in Exchange using Exchange Web Services

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Is it possible, using the EWS Managed API, to load the list of all in-place holds in Exchange, with the hold name and hold id? I can see how to get the details of a single hold, using the hold ID - but I need to enumerate all of the existing holds.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying EWS operation will allow it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj219984(v=exchg.150).aspx . The way the EWS Managed API methods are  written at the moment requires a HoldId. So if you use Raw SOAP or EWS Proxy code you should be able to get it to work. Otherwise you could add your own overload or new method and add it to the EWS Managed API source on github https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api/blob/154dbc66ac018d861c73ce489839cd9f58a1b0cd/Core/Requests/GetHoldOnMailboxesRequest.cs